# Injecting a singleton service in angular2

Tags: dependency-injection, angular, angular2-di

I have a service for sharing data between components and other services. I'm injecting it into components and services with angular's DI. The service stores some data in its properties (non-statically). I also user a ComponentResolver to dynamically create and load components and then destroy them. The problem is ... if i inject such a service in a component using simply:

```
constructor(private myService: MyDataService) { ... }
```

A new instance of this server is injected each time and the data is lost. I could store the data statically, but then there are observers that subscribe to this data. Long story short - too many things to refactor into static variables. Is there some sort of way to tell angular's DI to only create one instance of this service and share it in every single injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Angulars DI maintains a single instance **per provider**

If you provide the service only once (root component or `bootstrap()`) then there will be only one instance and every service or component that injects it will get the same instance.

**update**

Yes, you **have to** use

```ts
@NgModule({
  providers: [MyService],
  ...,
})
export class AppModule {}
```

or

```ts
@Component({ 
  selector: 'my-app', 
  providers: [MyService], 
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

(or alternatively `viewProviders`)

to provide injectables, but if you want to have **singletons ensure that you provide an injectable only once**.

If you provide the same injectable more than once, than the component where you provide it and all its descendants get the instance from this provider, instead of the one from an ancestor where it might be also provided.

DI is hierarchical and looks from the current component towards root component and `AppModule` for a provider. It injects the instance from the first provider it finds this way.

Comment: Right, Don't you have to use the boostrap or at least  a view provider to use the DI in the constructor? It's my understanding that all Injected services are singletons, I didn't know it was possible to do it as new instances..

Comment: I updated my answer because it was to long for a comment.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer but is there a way to force an Injectable to be provided only in AppComponent and not others?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. You can "override" at a lower level, but you can not enforce a specific instance from a higher level.